# Replace WndProc with JNA fails with Exception

Tags: java, windows, jna, wndproc

I try to catch Windows Messages in a Java program using JNA to inject my own WndProc method. As I'll only be interested in a few message types, I'll have to forward the messages to the previous WndProc. In my test (Java 1.7.0_03, 64-bit, on Windows 7) this forwarding seems to fail as soon as I move my mouse over the created window, giving me the following exception:

```
com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2]The system cannot find the file specified.
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeLong(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:347)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:276)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:216)
    at $Proxy0.CallWindowProc(Unknown Source)
    at JnaWinEvents$1.callback(JnaWinEvents.java:102)
    at ...
```

Which I think is strange, because what file do I try to access? I guess there is something going utterly wrong with some memory access or so... :(

I'm using the newest version of JNA, 3.4.0. Many code examples I found here or in other places on the internet seem to use JNA 3.2.x (any version before the splitting into jna.jar and platform.jar) where User32 defined some methods well suited for this kind of work. In the newer versions of JNA/platform, those methods are missing. That's why I define most of the types on my own, only using jna.jar, but not platform.jar.
In the following is the code I use to test, and which generates the Exception. Any idea what's going wrong and why the exception occurs?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;

public class JnaWinEvents extends JFrame {

public LONG_PTR prevWndProc = null; // so it won't get GC'ed
public User32.WNDPROC wndProcCallbackListener = null; // so it won't get GC'ed

public JnaWinEvents() {
    this.add(new JLabel("Hello StackExchange!"));
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    setupEventsListener();
}

public static class LONG_PTR extends IntegerType {
    public LONG_PTR() {
        this(0);
    }
    public LONG_PTR(long value) {
        super(Pointer.SIZE, value);
    }
}

static class HANDLE extends PointerType implements NativeMapped {
}

public static class HWND extends HANDLE {
    public HWND() {
    }
}

public static class UINT_PTR extends IntegerType {
    public UINT_PTR() {
        super(Pointer.SIZE);
    }
    public UINT_PTR(long value) {
        super(Pointer.SIZE, value);
    }
    public Pointer toPointer() {
        return Pointer.createConstant(longValue());
    }
}

public static class WPARAM extends UINT_PTR {
    public WPARAM() {
        this(0);
    }
    public WPARAM(long value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

public static class LPARAM extends LONG_PTR {
    public LPARAM() {
        this(0);
    }
    public LPARAM(long value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

public static class LRESULT extends LONG_PTR {
    public LRESULT() {
        this(0);
    }
    public LRESULT(long value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    static int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;

    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    interface WNDPROC extends StdCallCallback {
        LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM uParam, LPARAM lParam);
    }

    LONG_PTR GetWindowLongPtr(HWND hWnd, int nIndex) throws LastErrorException;

    LRESULT CallWindowProc(LONG_PTR proc, HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM uParam, LPARAM lParam) throws LastErrorException;

    LONG_PTR SetWindowLongPtr(HWND hWnd, int nIndex, WNDPROC wndProc) throws LastErrorException;
}


private void setupEventsListener() {
    HWND hWnd = new HWND();
    hWnd.setPointer(Native.getWindowPointer(this));
    this.prevWndProc = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, User32.GWL_WNDPROC);
    this.wndProcCallbackListener = new User32.WNDPROC()
    {
        @Override
        public LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
        {
            System.out.println(hWnd + "\t" + uMsg + "\t" + wParam + "\t" + lParam);

            //Call the window's actual WndProc so the events get processed.
            return User32.INSTANCE.CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("FINALIZE!!!!");
            super.finalize();
        }
    };

    //Set the WndProc function to use our callback listener instead of the window's one. 
    LONG_PTR result = User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, User32.GWL_WNDPROC, wndProcCallbackListener);
    System.out.println("setting my window proc, result = " + result);
    System.out.println("old pointer = " + this.prevWndProc);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JnaWinEvents();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The message text might not be relevant because `LastErrorException` is being thrown as a result of an explicit test of the return code of the last function call. Better check what that code **2** means in the context of your specific function call.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in interface definition. Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/jdeskbar/source/browse/appbar/src/main/java/jdesktop/appbar/win32/User32.java?r=0c5f8b79a364a7500dbc3550a42dac9ce071b393)

Answer (score 0):

i had somme issues with JNA recently (because i tried to follow tutorials based on old releases). I just set up a skeleton of working code, i will not post it here because it is pretty similar to yours. The difference is that i am using platform.jar. Why dont you use it ?

Edit : sorry for the delay.
You need to define the callback procedure this way (StdCallBack is provided for you)

```
public class WndProc implements StdCallCallback {
    public LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    }
}
```

Declare it somewhere

```
private final WndProc procedure = new WndProc();
```

Then link it when appropriate.

```
user32.SetWindowLongPtr(window, com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.GWL_WNDPROC, procedure);
```

You may need to declare SetWindowLongPtr in a custom User32 interface which extends the provided one.

Comment: Which version of JNA do you use? In 3.4.0 that I'm using, WNDPROC which I need to implement is not defined, and CallWindowProc is missing as well in jna.jar and in platform.jar. Do you have a working example that replaces the wndproc *and* calls the original method? If yes, please post your code even if it is very similar. I mainly have the problem that calling the original wndproc does not work in all cases...